# Do we, today, cause the Churban?

Tags: tefilla, sin, rosh-chodesh-new-month, musaf, churban-destruction

When, in musaf for Shabbat Rosh Chodesh, we recall the destruction of the Beit Hamikdash, the text indicates not just that our forefathers were responsible for sinning that caused the destruction, or at least one of them, but that we, distinct from them, caused it. The text in my siddur reads "וּלְפִי שֶׁחָטָאנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ אֲנַחְנוּ וַאֲבותֵינוּ חָרְבָה עִירֵנוּ וְשָׁמֵם בֵּית מִקְדָּשֵׁנוּ". (In the musaf for yom tov, it seems that we as a collective whole were responsible for the exile)

Is this saying that our current sins are continually destroying the temple (and if so, isn't our use of liturgy which insists that we continually sin making it impossible to conceive of a rebuilding)? Or is this saying that, in the same way that [all](https://www.aish.com/atr/A_Converts_Soul.html) Jewish souls were at Sinai, somehow, all souls were there to be complicit in the destruction?

Comment: “Any generation in which it [the BHM] was not rebuilt that generation is considered to have caused its destruction” ([PT Yoma 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Yoma.5a.1?with=all&lang=bi))

Comment: The Chafetz Chaim, in the introduction to his Sefer of that name, also says the same idea, that Hashem would rebuild the Bais Hamikdash if the sins that caused it to be destroyed would be rectified. https://www.sefaria.org/Chofetz_Chaim%2C_Preface.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35843/170 & https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94062/170

Comment: @Oliver If I give my 12 year old son a siddur on R"C then he starts putting blame on himself (and his "generation") even before he could have been considered responsible. The text becomes predictive and deterministic.

Comment: @Oliver oops, I haven't seen your comment. make it an answer and I will erase mine.

Comment: @rosends I don’t think the liturgists took into consideration what a 12yo would glean from their texts, same goes for a 12yo reading Eleh Ezkerah or the like. I also don’t think the authors intended to always use their poetry as means of communicating definitive theological lessons. (No minors were harmed in the development of this theory.)

Comment: @Alaychem I prob won’t add anything so you can keep it up. No worries.

Comment: @Oliver-good quote.  Should be sent daily to members of the Israeli Government as a Good Morning reminder.  And posted in all public areas there.

Answer (score 3):

The potential of rebuilding the Temple is constantly present:

סנהדרין צח ע"א

> ר' יהושע בן לוי אשכח לאליהו ... אמר ליה אימת אתי משיח אמר ליה זיל
>   שייליה לדידיה ... א"ל לאימת אתי מר א"ל היום אתא לגבי אליהו...א"ל הכי
>   אמר לך (תהלים צה, ז) היום אם בקולו תשמעו

Sanhedrin 98a

R' Yehosuah Ben Levi found *Eliahu*... He told him, when the messiah will come? He replied, go and ask him... He asked (the messiah) when mister will come? the messiah replied today. He went back to *Eliahu*... *Eliahu* told to him, that what the messiah told you, today, if you will obey his words (Psalms 95:7).

And not fulfilling this potential, is as bad as causing the *Churban* (destruction of the Temple)

ירושלמי יומא דף ה עמוד א

> אמרו כל דור שאינו נבנה בימיו מעלין עליו כאילו הוא החריבו

Yerushalmi Yoma 5a

They said: every generation that the temple is not built at it's days, is considered like it destroyed the temple

Comment: Doesn't this only apply to the past generations? The current generation still has a chance

Comment: Our generation is currently at fault for not having built the Temple yet. In previous generations we could blame the Temple not being built on outside forces, but today, if we as a nation, coherently and in totality, wanted to build the Temple, do you really think we wouldn't?

Comment: @DoubleAA  היום אם בקולו תשמעו  Sanhedrin 98a

Comment: @Alaychem that should be your answer, instead of the thing you posted which doesn't apply.

Comment: @DoubleAA You could say, that not building it is not as bad as ruining it, so both should be in the answer. I updated my answer.